# What are the rules for wearing the Sikha?

Tags: dress

What are the rules for wearing the [Sikha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikha#Procedure)?

Can you wear a Sikha even if you haven't done the [Chudakarana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudakarana)?

Comment: Isn't it wearing? it seems like hair style, just shaved off hair from sides and leave hair left on top or on the back of the shaven head on Sikha style.. Our tradition people believe hair from birth is associated with undesirable traits from past lives. At the time of the Chudakarana or mundana, the child is freshly shaven to signify freedom from the past and moving into the future.

Comment: @CR241 Right but do I need to chant any mantras.

Comment: Mantras are required to be chanted while securing the knot .. my answer contains some mantras... the mantras that are used in your region/tradition might be different .,. @Ikshvaku